# missing "restore missing files" option

Tags: files, backup, menu, restore

I want to restore files that I accidentally removed from my computer.

I use ubuntu 20.04 as my OS, Files (3.36.3-stable) as the file manager, and Déjà Dup Backup Tool (40.7) as the backup program

The Help for Déjà Dup Backup Tool says that in order to restore missing files:

Backup Help › Restoring Files »
Restoring a Lost File
Browse to the folder containing the file you lost.
Click *File ▸ Restore Missing Files…*.
When the Restore dialog appears, it will scan for files that are in the backup but no longer in the folder.
When you see the file you want to restore appear, select it and click Forward.
Review your selections and click Restore.

I am unable to find a menu "File",  much less an menu item "Restore Missing Files….".

There is probably an extension that I need, but I haven't found a reference to support that thought.

Thanks

John

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do and even less clear *why*. Please edit your question accordingly. And no, Files has no traditional menus just like many other Gnome apps. The menu is exactly those 3 lines, the rightmost button in the top bar.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - edited original post, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I removed Déjà Dup and then reinstalled it.

sudo apt-get remove deja-dup
sudo apt-get install  deja-dup

then rebooted and logged in. Now if I right click in the folder, I have the menu item "Restore Missing Files…."

Thanks. Sorry for the bother.

John